# Google Custom Search Quota Hit: Site Restricted Queries per user per 100 seconds

Tags: api, google-custom-search

I'm hitting the 100 seconds per user site restricted google custom search quota. I have unlimited queries plan and am getting billed. I don't pass in the userId so I'm not sure how it's limiting me. From the console I see the site restricted rate as 100 per user per 100 seconds. Can I just feed in random strings as the user id to help solve this? I've read the docs and they're not useful and have found other people ask this without an answer.

Help would be appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP.

Comment: I don't think there's a code problem. I'm just making a request to google custom search restricted api. It works fine it's just this quota that hits very often and I haven't found good explanations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass a user ID, then all of your queries are considered to be coming from a single user.

Passing a user ID with your requests will apply the capping correctly per user.

See the "[Capping API Usage](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_second_per_user)" doc for more info.

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried the quotaUser parameter with a different value for each request. I'm still running into the quota. I don't think it works.

Comment: As jira mentioned that's the issue I'm seeing. Just generating random user id's does not seem to work. I'd love to see if anyone has gotten around this!